# Daniel 9:24 -- The purpose and meaning of the words in brackets?

Tags: translation

> שָׁבֻעִ֨ים שִׁבְעִ֜ים נֶחְתַּ֥ךְ עַֽל־עַמְּךָ֣ ׀ וְעַל־עִ֣יר
> קׇדְשֶׁ֗ךָ לְכַלֵּ֨א הַפֶּ֜שַׁע (ולחתם) [וּלְהָתֵ֤ם] (חטאות)
> [חַטָּאת֙] וּלְכַפֵּ֣ר עָוֺ֔ן וּלְהָבִ֖יא צֶ֣דֶק עֹֽלָמִ֑ים
> וְלַחְתֹּם֙ חָז֣וֹן וְנָבִ֔יא וְלִמְשֹׁ֖חַ קֹ֥דֶשׁ קׇֽדָשִֽׁים׃
>
> “Seventy weeks have been decreed for your people and your holy city
> until the measure of transgression is filled and that of sin complete,
> until iniquity is expiated, and eternal righteousness ushered in; and
> prophetic vision ratified, and the Holy of Holies anointed.

What is the purpose of the words in brackets and parenthesis, and how should they be translated?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qere_and_Ketiv

Comment: As JoelK noted -- sometimes there's a variation between what would be written in a handwritten scroll, and the way it should be pronounced. The most striking cases of these are where the word that's written is a vulgar term for bodily functions, and it's replaced (in pronunciation) with a euphemism.  But in this case, it's a difference of two letters, and only a finely nuanced meaning: as written it would translate "and to seal off sins", but as pronounced it's "to expiate sin." Same idea.

Comment: Thanks... So if I understand right "Because the difference between the qere and ketiv is relatively large, a note is made in footnotes, sidenotes or brackets to indicate it." (But it so happens in this case that it's a minor difference in pronunciation resulting a difference  in a difference of meaning that worth noting.)

Comment: In a printed Jewish Bible, typically they'll put one version inline with the text, and the other in a footnote/margin. I'm not aware of those that differentiate between major and minor differences. In most digital files, where someone expects a single blob of "the text", they indicate both inline somehow, e.g. this edition put the Ketiv in round parentheses, followed by the Qeri in square brackets. In this case it would appear like this in English:

Comment: (Ulchatam) [Ulhatem]  (Chataot) [Chatat].    (And to seal off) [And to expiate] (Sins) [Sin].

Answer (score -2):

If you look in the introduction to that particular printed edition carefully, you will probably find an explanation about the various manuscripts used  by the editor. The brackets and parentheses indicate which manuscript provided a particular textual variation. The parentheses indicate one manuscript and the brackets indicate another.

In your example, the main textual version is:

שָׁבֻעִ֨ים שִׁבְעִ֜ים נֶחְתַּ֥ךְ עַֽל־עַמְּךָ֣ ׀ וְעַל־עִ֣יר קׇדְשֶׁ֗ךָ לְכַלֵּ֨א הַפֶּ֜שַׁע וּלְכַפֵּ֣ר עָוֺ֔ן וּלְהָבִ֖יא צֶ֣דֶק עֹֽלָמִ֑ים וְלַחְתֹּם֙ חָז֣וֹן וְנָבִ֔יא וְלִמְשֹׁ֖חַ קֹ֥דֶשׁ קׇֽדָשִֽׁים׃

The two alternative textual variations are:

שָׁבֻעִ֨ים שִׁבְעִ֜ים נֶחְתַּ֥ךְ עַֽל־עַמְּךָ֣ ׀ וְעַל־עִ֣יר קׇדְשֶׁ֗ךָ לְכַלֵּ֨א הַפֶּ֜שַׁע ולחתם חטאות וּלְהָבִ֖יא צֶ֣דֶק עֹֽלָמִ֑ים וְלַחְתֹּם֙ חָז֣וֹן וְנָבִ֔יא וְלִמְשֹׁ֖חַ קֹ֥דֶשׁ קׇֽדָשִֽׁים׃

and:

שָׁבֻעִ֨ים שִׁבְעִ֜ים נֶחְתַּ֥ךְ עַֽל־עַמְּךָ֣ ׀ וְעַל־עִ֣יר קׇדְשֶׁ֗ךָ לְכַלֵּ֨א הַפֶּ֜שַׁע וּלְהָתֵ֤ם חַטָּאת֙ וּלְהָבִ֖יא צֶ֣דֶק עֹֽלָמִ֑ים וְלַחְתֹּם֙ חָז֣וֹן וְנָבִ֔יא וְלִמְשֹׁ֖חַ קֹ֥דֶשׁ קׇֽדָשִֽׁים׃

Comment: So not a question of pronunciation, but of textual variants? That's what I thought originally, but @Shalom's answer also makes sense. I'm even more perplexed now than when I started ;-)

Comment: @DanFefferman Like I emphasized in the opening words of the answer, you should first be reading the introduction to the particular edition that you are learning from. There are usually explicit statements from that editor about how to understand editorial marks within that edition. It doesn't have to be as I presented here. But what I wrote in this answer is one of the more common usages.

Comment: @DanFefferman Also, in most published texts that I have used, the "Kri v'Kativ" is usually set off as a special commentary to the page with only a single notation icon (like an asterisk, etc) at the body text.